# Can't figure out schematics error

Tags: dac

ATTiny is generating PWM based tones with 32kHz sampling rate. Then I've created R-2R DAC and then trying to amplify it for speaker. However, LM386 is sinking signal from R-2R. If I don't connect LM386 then there is signal on DAC output. How to correct this circuit?

Also I'm planing to make low pass filter, to filter out PWM hiss during playback and some white noise during silence. But I will open separate question for that.

[image]

Comment: There's a minor error in your DAC: R4 should be 20K (not 10K). But I have no idea about the answer to your main question. When the signal dies, do you still see toggling at the output pins of the MCU?

Comment: There are some strange clicks on R-2R output, which corresponds to my control SPI signalling, which is not shown here. What I tried is to remove LM386 and connect high impedance external amplifier to R-2R out and the signal is fine then.

Comment: I take it you don't have a scope, then. OK, what happens if you connect both amplifiers simultaneously? What if you connect any other signal source to the input of the LM386?

Comment: yep, ain't got scope... if I connect both amplifiers, I just hear series of clicks whenever tone supposed to be played back. If I remove ATTiny and connect external audio source to pin 3 of LM386 it amplifies the signal as expected.

Comment: So, for some reason, the MCU is not generating the tone when the LM386 is connected. Do you have bypass capacitors on the power supply pins of all ICs?

Comment: The power supply to this circuit is going from Arduino, so I haven't connected any capacitors to VCC.

Comment: I suggest you try powering the LM386 from a different 5V source. If that solves it you might need a big decoupling capacitor near the LM386.

Comment: I've tried to power this circuit from batter, which gives 5V. Same result.

Comment: in my opinion the problem could be R-2R values not good enough for LM386 for some reason.

Comment: Throw the LM386 in the garbage where it belongs and get another audio amp chip. There are plenty out there. Surely you can find something with a higher input impedance **and** bridged speaker output terminals (so you will save space on your board by eliminating he footprint for the 220 uF-fer).

Comment: @Kaz tell me examples where the price is almost same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LM386 has a ground-referenced input according to its [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) so you need an AC coupling capacitor ( 1uF or so will do; even 0.1uf unless you need bass!) between the DAC output and pin 3.

As it is now, if you have a meter, you will probably find Vout (pin 5) is very close to Vcc (5V) instead of Vcc/2 (2.5V).

Comment: I've tried to connect 4.7uF between ground and pin 3, still no tone, just described clicks. Yes, on pin5 the voltage is about Vcc.

Comment: COUPLING not decoupling capacitor! From pin 3 to R1/R3, replacing the wire.

Comment: If in doubt, look at Cc on page 6 of the datasheet. Don't bother with the resistors or C1 unless it's too loud or distorted - though it probably will be, since the gain is 20...

Comment: The AC coupling capacitor solved the issue. thank you. I'm just not sure what type it has to be. The value is 1uF now.

Comment: Type is not critical. But if it's electrolytic or tantalum, + goes to the DAC.

Answer (score 0):

The LM386 has a fixed *minimum* gain of 20. As such, no matter what your DAC value is, you're going to get 5V as the output.

If you want to buffer the output of your R2R DAC, you'll need to use a proper op-amp. Something like a [TL081](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl084.pdf) would work.